# Cursor Toad DB2 always getting null error when variables ok

Tags: sql, db2, toad

Basically I have a cursor declared with a prepared query and when I try to open the cursor it always gives me the **error 22004** which is about null values being passed to the cursor but I've put the variables in an auxiliar table and they are all ok and with values. I know that I_EXP_DATE,I_ESTADO_LOCAL_CC,I_ESTADO_LOCAL_CIRURGICO,I_ID_DETALHES_LOCAL all have values that are not null. What am I doing wrong here?

```
DECLARE query_stmt VARCHAR(8000) DEFAULT '';
DECLARE cursorResults_anular CURSOR;

SET query_stmt = 'SELECT DISTINCT LC.ID_LOCAL_ATENDIMENTO, LC.ID_ENTIDADE, LR.REDE, LR.SUB_REDE, 333, LR.DATA_ANULACAO, LR.DIRECTORIO_CLINICO, LR.ID_USER, LR.ID_CONTRATO_RIOS, LR.ID_CONTRATO_RIOS2, LR.INICIO_CONTRATO, LR.ID_DETALHES_LOCAL, LA.ID_ENTIDADE_DETENTORA, LC.PRACTICE_SEQ, LR.EXTERNO ' ||
                       'FROM ICARO.LOCAL_REDE LR JOIN ICARO.LOCAL_CORPO_CLINICO LC ON LC.ID_DETALHES_LOCAL = LR.ID_DETALHES_LOCAL ' ||
                       'JOIN ICARO.LOCAL_ATENDIMENTO LA ON LA.ID_LOCAL_ATENDIMENTO = LC.ID_LOCAL_ATENDIMENTO ' ||
                       'WHERE LR.DATA_ANULACAO = ? AND LR.ESTADO_CONTRATACAO in (?,?) AND LR.ID_CONTRATO_RIOS IS NOT NULL AND LC.ID_DETALHES_LOCAL = ?';   
PREPARE query_pstmt_anular FROM query_stmt;
OPEN cursorResults_anular USING I_EXP_DATE,I_ESTADO_LOCAL_CC,I_ESTADO_LOCAL_CIRURGICO,I_ID_DETALHES_LOCAL;
FETCH cursorResults_anular INTO I_ID_LOCAL,I_ID_ENTIDADE_CC,I_ID_REDE,I_SUB_REDE,I_ESTADO_CONTRATACAO,I_DATA_ANULACAO,I_DIRECTORIO_CLINICO,I_ID_USER,I_ID_CONTRATO_RIOS,I_ID_CONTRATO_RIOS2,I_INICIO_CONTRATO,I_ID_DETALHES_LOCAL,I_ID_ENTIDADE_DETENTORA,I_PRACTICE_SEQ_CC, I_EXTERNO;
        WHILE SQLCODE = 0 DO
  
   

FETCH cursorResults_anular INTO I_ID_LOCAL,I_ID_ENTIDADE_CC,I_ID_REDE,I_SUB_REDE,I_ESTADO_CONTRATACAO,I_DATA_ANULACAO,I_DIRECTORIO_CLINICO,I_ID_USER,I_ID_CONTRATO_RIOS,I_ID_CONTRATO_RIOS2,I_INICIO_CONTRATO,I_ID_DETALHES_LOCAL,I_ID_ENTIDADE_DETENTORA,I_PRACTICE_SEQ_CC,I_EXTERNO;
      END WHILE;
      CLOSE cursorResults_anular;
```

The cursor runs within a procedure and it should retrieve all the values that match the conditions of the query.

Comment: Your question does not contain enough facts to give an answer. The SQLSTATE 22204 means "A null value cannot be returned either from a procedure defined as PARAMETER STYLE GENERAL, or from a type-preserving method invoked with a non-null argument. "     What is the signature of your procedure? (i.e. what is the full `create procedure` for it), the message suggests that  it is the *returned value* (one or more columns) that has a null , which is disallowed.

Comment: Try to provide some fully reproducible example like [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/wE-OQzHg). Edit the code at the link (you may create your routine with one statement and call it with a 2-nd one) and provide the corresponding link here to show the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> The cursor runs within a procedure and it should retrieve all the
> values that match the conditions of the query.

As I read that statement, you are expecting to get multiple records back, aka a results set.
But your code has this

```
FETCH cursorResults_anular INTO I_ID_LOCAL,I_ID_ENTIDADE_CC,I_ID_REDE,I_SUB_REDE,I_ESTADO_CONTRATACAO,I_DATA_ANULACAO,I_DIRECTORIO_CLINICO,I_ID_USER,I_ID_CONTRATO_RIOS,I_ID_CONTRATO_RIOS2,I_INICIO_CONTRATO,I_ID_DETALHES_LOCAL,I_ID_ENTIDADE_DETENTORA,I_PRACTICE_SEQ_CC, I_EXTERNO;
        WHILE SQLCODE = 0 DO
FETCH cursorResults_anular INTO I_ID_LOCAL,I_ID_ENTIDADE_CC,I_ID_REDE,I_SUB_REDE,I_ESTADO_CONTRATACAO,I_DATA_ANULACAO,I_DIRECTORIO_CLINICO,I_ID_USER,I_ID_CONTRATO_RIOS,I_ID_CONTRATO_RIOS2,I_INICIO_CONTRATO,I_ID_DETALHES_LOCAL,I_ID_ENTIDADE_DETENTORA,I_PRACTICE_SEQ_CC,I_EXTERNO;
      END WHILE;
      CLOSE cursorResults_anular;
```

That's not how you return a results set from Db2.

Basically, to return a results set, simply declare you cursor as being returned (to CALLER or CLIENT), open the cursor then end your proc.

```
DECLARE query_stmt VARCHAR(8000) DEFAULT '';
DECLARE cursorResults_anular CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CLIENT;

SET query_stmt = 'SELECT DISTINCT LC.ID_LOCAL_ATENDIMENTO, LC.ID_ENTIDADE, LR.REDE, LR.SUB_REDE, 333, LR.DATA_ANULACAO, LR.DIRECTORIO_CLINICO, LR.ID_USER, LR.ID_CONTRATO_RIOS, LR.ID_CONTRATO_RIOS2, LR.INICIO_CONTRATO, LR.ID_DETALHES_LOCAL, LA.ID_ENTIDADE_DETENTORA, LC.PRACTICE_SEQ, LR.EXTERNO ' ||
                       'FROM ICARO.LOCAL_REDE LR JOIN ICARO.LOCAL_CORPO_CLINICO LC ON LC.ID_DETALHES_LOCAL = LR.ID_DETALHES_LOCAL ' ||
                       'JOIN ICARO.LOCAL_ATENDIMENTO LA ON LA.ID_LOCAL_ATENDIMENTO = LC.ID_LOCAL_ATENDIMENTO ' ||
                       'WHERE LR.DATA_ANULACAO = ? AND LR.ESTADO_CONTRATACAO in (?,?) AND LR.ID_CONTRATO_RIOS IS NOT NULL AND LC.ID_DETALHES_LOCAL = ?';   
PREPARE query_pstmt_anular FROM query_stmt;
OPEN cursorResults_anular USING I_EXP_DATE,I_ESTADO_LOCAL_CC,I_ESTADO_LOCAL_CIRURGICO,I_ID_DETALHES_LOCAL;
```